# OS X: menu naming (File Edit View ... Windows Help)

Tags: macos, language-agnostic, user-interface

Apple suggests to stick with the known menu naming: File Edit View ... Windows Help. What to do if our application does not work on files directly, but rather on "*projects*" (a *project* may work on multiple directory structures)? Should I rename "File" to "Project" or use "File" though the menu items operate on projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use 'Project' because it more accurately reflects your user's mental model while they use your app.

A nice rule of thumb is to ask yourself how easy this is to document. If it's hard to document it is probably hard to use. Saying "to work with a project, first open the 'File' menu..." is clunky and, for me, falls into the "hard to document" category.

Answer (score 0):

I would rename File to project then. Other Mac OS X applications do the same, however I have none on my mind right now.